# GMP: how to write a number as a decimal value?

Tags: c++, decimal, gmp

I have an `mpq_class` instance, and I want to display it as a decimal value, rather than a fraction.

```
mpq_class nb = 1.75;
cout << nb << endl;
```

Output:

```
7/4
```

How can I output `1.75` rather than `7/4`?

Comment: If you check the documentation, there are member functions that will do what you want.  For instance, check out the get_d() and/or get_str() member functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest approach would probably be to convert to `mpf_class`, e.g. `cout << mpf_class(nb) << endl;`. You might need to explicitly set the output precision to avoid printing out garbage from floating point errors though.